# Syntax Error in my SQL request

Tags: sql, syntax, odbc

I'm currently working on a project where I automatize creation and launching of requests, but one of them is getting me in trouble.

```
UPDATE  F_COMPTET 
SET     CT_TYPE = 0, 
        N_RISQUE = 1, 
        N_PERIOD = 1, 
        N_EXPEDITION = 1, 
        N_CONDITION = 1, 
        CT_NUMPAYEUR = 'C14029', 
        CT_INTITULE = 'FOURNIER JEREMY', 
        CT_CLASSEMENT = 'FOURNIER JEREMY', 
        CT_CONTACT = 'FOURNIER JEREMY', 
        CT_ADRESSE = '3902 RUE SAINT BRICE', 
        CT_COMPLEMENT = '', 
        CT_CODEREGION = 'BE', 
        CT_CODEPOSTAL = '7500', 
        CT_VILLE = 'TOURNAI', 
        CT_PAYS = 'BELGIUM', 
        CT_TELEPHONE = '', 
        CT_EMAIL = 'jerem313@msn.com', 
        CG_NUMPRINC = '412060', 
        N_CATCOMPTA = 5, 
        CT_QUALITE = 'M', 
        N_CATTARIF = 1, 
        CEHC = 'CE', 
        PAYSISO = 'FR', 
        CBMODIFICATION = '2014-06-13' 
WHERE   CT_NUM = 'C14029'
```

When I launch it, ODBC give me that:

```
[Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver]Syntax Error.37000
```

We tried, but we don't find where the problem is, could you help us?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious like a misplaced quote or comma sticking out as being incorrect.  Without knowing your table structure, I really can't say.

Comment: Try setting a few values at a time to figure out the par giving the error. Maybe a mismatched data type?

Answer (score 0):

37000 is the ODBC2 error code for syntax error or access violation (now 42000 in ODBC3), so if you verify the code is syntactically correct it is likely the user running it does not have permission to update the target table.